# Data transfer by TabLayout to ViewPager (Adapter: FragmentPagerAdapter)

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to show ViewPager by TabLayout. Each Tab represents the Class of Parts. That is, Tab 1,2,3, ... is a class of Battery, Brake, Wiper, ... classes that extends class Parts. However, I only need one ViewPager, and it should show the information about the selected tab.

So, when I change the tab, it should change the data inside the fragment of the ViewPager. (ViewPager is adapted by FragmentPagerAdapter). Here's what I tried so far.

This is where the ViewPager and TabLayout is called.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_main_car_manager, container, false);

    activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    manager_layout = view.findViewById(R.id.manager_tab_layout);
    managerPager = view.findViewById(R.id.managerPager);

    parts_list_ex = new ArrayList<>(); 

    parts_list_ex.add(new Battery());
    parts_list_ex.add(new Brake());
    parts_list_ex.add(new Wiper());

    // These are the 2 fragments for the viewpager
    progressFragment = new ManagerProgressFragment(parts_list_ex.get(0));
    helperFragment = new ManagerHelperFragment(parts_list_ex.get(0));

    // since this is also a fragment
    manager = getChildFragmentManager();


    fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    fragmentList.add(progressFragment);
    fragmentList.add(helperFragment);


    adapter = new PartsManagerPagerAdapter(activity, manager, fragmentList);

    managerPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    manager_layout.setOnTabSelectedListener(tabListener);

    return view;
}
```

This is my TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener tabListener.

```
TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener tabListener = new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        int i = tab.getPosition();

        Parts selectedParts = parts_list_ex.get(i);

        progressFragment = new ManagerProgressFragment(selectedParts);
        helperFragment = new ManagerHelperFragment(selectedParts);

        fragmentList.clear();
        fragmentList.add(progressFragment);
        fragmentList.add(helperFragment);

        adapter.setFragmentList(fragmentList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // I think this is a part that doesn't work.

    }
```

And this is my Adapter.

```
public class PartsManagerPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

Activity activity;

ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList;

public PartsManagerPagerAdapter(Activity activity, FragmentManager manager, ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList) {

    super(manager);

    this.activity = activity;

    this.fragmentList = fragmentList;

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return fragmentList.get(position);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}


public void setFragmentList(ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList) {
    this.fragmentList = fragmentList;
}

public ArrayList<Fragment> getFragmentList() {
    return this.fragmentList;
}
}
```

It does not show an error on creating the page, but the datas are not transferred! It keeps showing the first tab's information even though I change the tab. I think `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is not working.

I tried a lot of solutions but this is the best I got.  Is there other way?